# A measure space where $p < q$ and $L^p(\mu) \not\subset L^q(\mu) $?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, normed-spaces

I was thinking about inclusions of different $L^p$ spaces and came to this question.

I know the reverse direction is not difficult: take the space $(1, \infty)$ with the Lebesgue measure. Then for any $1 \leq p < q < \infty$, we can show that $L^q(\lambda) \not\subset L^p(\lambda)$  by selecting $f = \frac{1}{x^p}$. This function will be in $L^q$ but not in $L^p$ and the lack of inclusion follows.

However getting  $L^p(\mu) \not\subset L^q(\mu) $ is not going well for me. I'm guessing I have to find a good measure space $(X, A, \mu)$ that would make this possible. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Take a space reduced to a point....

Answer (score 3):

Take $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and consider $x^{-1/q}$.

Also in your example I think you want $x^{-1/p}$ instead.

Comment: Ah, yes! Typo, I meant $\frac{1}{x^{1/p}}$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a relevant fact that's not too hard to prove: Given a measure space, let $S=\{\mu(E): 0<\mu(E)<\infty\}$. Then $L^p\subset L^q$ whenever $p<q$ if and only if $\inf(S)>0$, while $L^p\subset L^q$ when $p>q$ if and only if $\sup(S)<\infty$.

So for example on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure $L^p\subset L^q$ if and only if $p\ge q$, while if we consider counting measure on any infinite set then $L^p\subset L^q$ if and only if $p\le q$. And on the line no $L^p$ is contained in any other. (Keep straight how it goes by example: It's obvious that $L^\infty((0,1))\subset L^1((0,1))$ and that $\ell_1\subset\ell_\infty$.)

Comment: @user726608 I answered exactly that question quite explicitly above.

Comment: I'm trying to find a counterexample that if $L^p\subset L^q$ then it is not true that $||f_p||<||f_q||$ where $1\leq p<q<\infty$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure. Can you help in that.

Comment: @user726608 Why would you think that $||f||_p\le||f||_q$ here? That would say $L^q\subset L^p$, so $L^q=L^p$. If you fix $p$ and $q$ there is a counterexample of the form $f(n)=n^\alpha$.

Comment: okay, I've tried what you said, taking alfa=-2 , p=1 and q=2 for example then I havr just show this by definition of p-norm and sum (which converges) ? @David C. Ullrich